# How can I detect an object that I see on screen using Raycasting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

So, I want to check if I see an object on screen. Using Raycasting of course.

Code:

```cs
private void SeeObject(){
  ISeeObj = false;
  if (Vector3.Dot(cam.transform.forward, (cam.transform.position - obj.transform.position).normalized) < -0.65f){
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, (obj.transform.position - cam.transform.position).normalized, out hit, range, layerMask)){
      if (hit.transform.name == obj.name){
        ISeeObj = true;
        Debug.Log("I see an Object");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also I've tried using

```cs
if (Vector3.Dot(cam.transform.forward,
(cam.transform.position - obj.transform.position).normalized) > 0 )
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code doesn't line up with the documentation at all https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Comment: If you already know the `obj` and can check it's position etc what do you need the Raycast for? Do you want to check whether it is blocked by anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to **not** use a `Raycast` for this.

---

`MonoBehaviour` already implements the two methods [`OnBecameVisible`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html)

> `OnBecameVisible` is called when the renderer became visible by any camera.
>
> This message is sent to all scripts attached to the renderer.

and

[`OnBecameInvisible`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html)

> `OnBecameInvisible` is called when the renderer is no longer visible by any camera.
>
> This message is sent to all scripts attached to the renderer.

(Both can also be Coroutines)

---

So if you need to constantly check if an object is currently visible attach a component like

```
public class VisibilityChecker : MonoBehaviour
{
    // E.g. using a read-only auto-property
    public bool IsVisible{ get; private set; }

    // If you rather like to be able to also see the value in the Inspector for debugging use
    //public bool IsVisible { get { return _isVisible;}}
    //[SerializeField] private bool _isVisible;

    private void OnBecameVisible()
    {
        IsVisible = true;

        //or
        //_isVisible = true;
    }

    private void OnBecameInvisible()
    {
        IsVisible = false;

        //or
        //_isVisible = false;
    }
}
```

And in another script e.g. check it in `Update` like

```
private VisibilityChecker objVisibilityChecker;

private void Awake()
{
    objVisibilityChecker = obj.GetComponent<VisibilityChecker>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if(objVisibilityChecker.IsVisible)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else
    {
        // Do another thing
    }
}
```